# Japan math Olympiad 2013 solution

Tags: geometry

[Here is the link to the problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h520424p2931214)

> Given an acute-angled triangle $ABC$, let $H$ be the orthocentre. A circle passing through the points $B,C$ and a circle with a diameter $AH$ intersect at two distinct points $X,Y$. Let $D$ be the foot of the perpendicular drawn from $A$ to line $BC$, and let $K$ be the foot of the perpendicular drawn from $D$ to line $XY$. Show that $\angle{BKD}=\angle{CKD}$.

[Here is my photo](https://m.imgur.com/a/mkNiiZf)

[image]
Could someone give me the proof with more details? I'm a normal high school student so I'm having a hard time understanding what's going on there.

For me I draw $BZ//XY$ and $BZ$ also intersect $P$, but I don't know whenever it  intersect or not.( sorry I'm not good at explaining it I hope you could take a look at my photo). Then I draw $YP$ and $KP$. For what I want is to prove that $KB=YP$ and $YP=KP$ so $KB=KP$ and since $BZ//XY$ so $\triangle{KBP}$ isosceles and $KD$ is the height so it prove the statement above. But I don't think everything will work as I plan out. So I come here searching for some help

Comment: Your photo link is broken.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork hello, sorry for the inconvenient I have made an edited now I hope you could take a look

Comment: Stackoverflow has the feature of uploading images.

Comment: @CroCo I upload photo in the app but they won't allow so I upload there hahaha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let M be the midpoint of BC.

The circle passing through B, Y, X, C is marked in green with center (G) located on the perpendicular bisector (MG) of BC.

[image]

Construct the red circle passing through BKC with center (R). Since BC is also a chord of the red circle, R is located somewhere on MG extended. Let the circle BKC cut XY at Z.

From the facts that (1) M(G)R is part of a diameter of the red circle; (2) K and Z are points on the red circle; and (3) $\angle ZKD = 90^0$, we can say that Z is one extremity of the diameter (RGM extended). Then, when KD extended meets Z(M)(G)R produced at T, T is another extremity of the mentioned diameter.

Therefore, T lies on the perpendicular bisector of BC. This means (chord TB) = (chord TC). This further leads to the result required.

Comment: Thank you, sir that's really helpful

Comment: @user635988 You are welcome. Hope that helps. In case you accept this as an answer, please tick it.